# php8.3 fails to load php8.3-ds extension

Tags: php, php-fpm

I'm trying php 8.3 (currently using 8.2 without problems), but now I get this when starting  apache php8.3-fpm:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ds.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/ds.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/ds.so: undefined symbol: fast_add_function), /usr/lib/php/20230831/ds.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/ds.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0`

I already checked and ds.so already exists with correct permissions.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? The latest version of PHP provided in Ubuntu repositories is 8.2: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php

Comment: I'm using the offical ppa: "ondrej/php" "ondrej/apache2"

Comment: If you are using Ondrej's PPA you need to contact them if the package is from their PPA.  Because thats an issue they need to fix that we are very limited to help with.

Comment: What release are you using? (*as previously asked, PPA's are 3rd party sources the name Personal Package Archive* should remind you of that*). Without release details we cannot know what libraries are expected for your *unstated* system.

Comment: Same problem. There's an issue opened here: https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/2063